# Get content after question mark in PHP if statement

Tags: php

I am setting up a separate theme page for printable content. To tell the browser to use the print theme I'm using a mark ?print after the URL.  So how does one get that content?

Something link

```
<?php if (? = 'print') {
   blah blah }
```

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `$_GET` array to access that.

If you want the whole string, use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

In your example, you'd do something like this...

```
if (isset($_GET['print'])) {
    // something.php?print
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can access the whole query string using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

So your code could look like this:

```
if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == 'print') { /* do something */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php):

```
$_GET['print']
```

> An associative array of variables
> passed to the current script via the
> URL parameters.

#### **Note:** Beware of security though, you need to sanitalize and validate any data coming from the URLs.

Answer (score -2):

Are you aware you can just set up a stylesheet for printing, this may suffice for your needs. Just add a line like the following after your standard css line.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```